# PHP: require_once library -> failed to open stream

Tags: php, class, require, require-once

I might be a bit confused and may need your help with this.
I'm inside `inc/newsletter.php` and want to include a library that is inside `lib/mailchimp-api-class`

How do I refer to this class file?

I thought it should be …

`require_once '../lib/mailchimp-api-class/MCAPI.class.php';`

[image]

However, this doesn't work …

```
Warning: require_once(../lib/mailchimp-api-class/MCAPI.class.php) [function.require-
once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/myname/htdocs/wr/
wp-content/themes/mytheme/inc/newsletter.php on line 6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're using WordPress. This is not working because the relative path is from the starting file.

**Try:**

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../lib/mailchimp-api-class/MCAPI.class.php';
```

**In PHP 5.3 or newer:**

you can use `__DIR__` instead of `dirname(__FILE__)`

Comment: /Users/myname/htdocs/wr/
wp-content/themes/mytheme/inc/newsletter.php on line 6 wp-content sounds a bit like workpress.

Answer (score 2):

If you're in an included file, then the current directory isn't necessarily that of said included file. You can always be absolute about it, though:

```
require_once dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/lib/mailchimp-api-class/MCAPI.class.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using absolute path:

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wr/wp-content/themes/mytheme/lib/mailchimp-api-class/MCAPI.class.php';
```